# Find a particular color in a 2D image

Tags: image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

What are some Algorithms that will detect or find a particular color (RGB) in an image. The detection will be purposely used as a marker to find position of the particular color which will then be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the color you can just look for it:

C++

```
glm::vec3 targetColor(1.0f,0,0);//(red,blue,green)
float accepted_color_distance = 0.1f; 
/*how much must look the colors alike? distance 0 means the colors must be equal,
but there are numeric precission problems. Use 0.0001f or 
something instead of 0.*/

bool markersFound[image.rows][image.cols]; //true means pixel y,x is a markers

for(unsigned int a = 0; a < image.rows; a++) //init markersFound with false
{
     for(unsigned int b = 0; b < image.cols; b++)
     { 
         bool markersFound[a][b] = false;
     }
}     

for(unsigned int a = 0; a < image.rows; a++)
{
     for(unsigned int b = 0; b < image.rows; b++)
     { 
       glm::vec3 currentColor = image.at(a,b);
       float color_distance = glm::distance(currentColor, targetColor);

       if(color_distance < accepted_color_distance) //if a marker is found save it
       {
         bool markersFound[a][b] = true;
       }
      }
 }
```

Comment: How about no? You can translate it yourself.   You should also update the tags in your post to indicate `C#`.  That way people won't waste their time in a language you don't desire.

Comment: Now you're entering SO:Homework. The new community site.